# ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Emscripten.clang)

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I was eventually trying to run this code in remix IDE, where I was running this using 0.6.6 version of Solidity and ran into this error. I've tried using some other versions like 0.8 and 0.6 as well.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity =0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract myContract{
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;
    mapping(address => uint256) public payTo;

    function Payment() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "Doesn't satisfy the minimum condition");
        payTo[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's literally no question here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code requires Solidity 0.8.7, but the imported [SafeMathChainlink.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol) requires Solidity 0.6.*.

An easy solution is to change your code to require v0.6 as well and compile with this version.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
```

Or you can remove the `import` and `using ... for` of the SafeMath library, as it's not needed on 0.8 anymore. All validations performed in the library are now performed on the language level since version 0.8.0.

Answer (score 2):

Now we can use this line of code to include a range of version of solidity to use. I faced the similar issue and got fixed by doing this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use pragma solidity ^0.8.0; as I fixed the issue by changing the version in brownie-config.yaml

version: 0.8.0

Comment: so it looks like this 
```
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.8.0
```

Comment: this should work assuming all the dependencies require the version in the brownie-config.yaml

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 < 0.9.0
```